# Passing arguments to an R script from command lines when the argument is a string

Tags: r, bash

I want to pass arguments to an R script from command lines when the argument is a string
I know that if the argument is a numeric value, I can write something in the command line :

`R CMD BATCH "--args CHR=1" rfile.R test.Rout`

But I want to input a file name such as "file1.txt" in r command. If I put

`R CMD BATCH "--args CHR=1 file="file1.txt" rfile.R test.Rout`

It does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple R script which would take string inputs:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
cat(args, sep = "\n")
```

I save the file as "test.R" in my home directory. In the command line I can then use:

```
Rscript test.R "file.txt"
```

The `"` are optional if your string does not have whitespace. But this would be recognised as two inputs:

```
Rscript test.R file 1.txt
```

There is a nice little tutorial from which I took this [here](http://swcarpentry.github.io/swc-releases/2017.08/r-novice-inflammation/05-cmdline/).

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!